# Linking error with g++ for static inline thread_local variable

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker, thread-local, header-only

I have three files I am compiling together using CMake (smallest example that produces the error):

## lib.h

```
#ifndef lib
#define lib

struct StructOuter{
    struct StructInner{
        int a;
        StructInner(int aa) {
            a = aa;
        }
    };

    static inline thread_local StructInner problemStruct{3};
};


#endif
```

## other.cpp

```
#include "lib.h"
```

## main.cpp

```
#include "lib.h"

int main() {
    StructOuter t = StructOuter{};
    return t.problemStruct.a;
}
```

## CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(proj)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(proj main.cpp other.cpp)
```

Here I get the error:

> multiple definition of `TLS init function for StructOuter::problemStruct' ... collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed

I get the error on my Windows computer where I am using Clion with g++ from MinGW with gcc 9.3 and compiling with C++20. More info:

1. With my understanding of static inline, it should exactly avoid that there are multiple definitions across different translation units like here.
2. Since the lib.h file is in the header-only library I do not want to change anything in there, I believe the error is somehow in my build setup.
3. The issue is gone when I remove the keyword 'thread_local'.
4. Changing to clang64 compiler on my Windows also fixes the problem, and the project compiles with no errors!

My best bet is that this is a bug in the g++ compiler (or linker) from MinGW (maybe same issue as mentioned here: [sourceware](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin/2019-November/243028.html)?). Any help in understanding what is going on is much appreciated.

Comment: Reproduced on GCC 13 from MSYS2.

Comment: I would try moving it around, e.g. `inline thread_local` at namespace scope, or `static thread_local` at function scope.

Comment: Just a bug - [Bug 81915 - bug with thread_local inline variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81915). And the linked bug [Bug 102398 - thread_local works incorrectly outside of main file](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102398) states there is a similar issue with having thread_local defined in a different file even without _inline_.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, do you mean for debugging purposes? As mentioned it occurs in the header-only library so I don't really want to "fix" it by changing it. Thanks for the response:)

Comment: All alternatives I suggested would work in a header-only library.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Point is, it is supposed to work already. As far as I can tell the error lies with the compiler and not the library (which I anyways am unable to change)

Comment: Yep, and I'm suggesting possible workarounds.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it is not a solution to change the library

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you're not the library author. Still, I'd send them a PR or at least a bug report.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255556/discussion-between-rosv-and-holyblackcat).